# (Android studio) ScrollView won't scroll all the way to the bottom

Tags: android, layout, view, scroll, frame

im trying to put a scroll view inside a frame layout. My scroll view is not scrolling all the way to bottom. this is my xml code. It is working when i give a padding to scroll view. but i need a better answer. because giving a padding will make a white margin below my application. Thank you!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    // this is your first layout to put the big image
    // use src or backgroud image as per requirement

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/overly" />
    </LinearLayout>

    // this is your bottom layout

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffc9c9c9"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Anna Huffmunster"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Colombo Sri lanka"
            android:id="@+id/txt_location"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="#696969"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"

            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/call_button"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:background="@drawable/chat_button"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                    android:background="@drawable/location_button"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="“Live each day as if your life had just begun.” "
                    android:id="@+id/txt_status"
                    android:textColor="#ffd9162d"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Birthday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="19 MAR 1992"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="79dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Profession"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Software Engineer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:maxWidth="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <TextView
                    android:text="dgsdfsdfdfsdfsdfvv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="dgsdfsdfdfsdfsdfvv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="dgsdfsdfdfsdfsdfvv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="dgsdfsdfdfsdfsdfvv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

// This is the imageview which overlay the first LinearLayout

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="122dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_profile_pic"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/stroke"/>
```

Comment: add some bottom padding to your layout